# Azure OMS vs Azure Monitor 2018

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-oms

There is a new "Azure Monitor" feature available where all sorts of monitoring(logs,scripting,alerts,etc) can be performed. This was released in September 2018.

If I understand correctly, prior to this Azure Operations Management Suite (OMS) helped perform monitoring. And Monitoring was just one aspect of OMS. As OMS did a lot more (DR, Automation, compliance, etc).

Is it true that OMS does not do monitoring anymore and he has handed it over to a non-OMS feature called Azure Monitor? And OMS continue to deliver other aspects mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor provides infrastructure metrics and logs for services in Microsoft Azure.

OMS is more suitable for hybrid environment. 
eg. Can be done by integrating with System Center.

Comment: Cloud sure is moving fast and furious... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/azure-monitor-rebrand#retirement-of-operations-management-suite-brand  OMS is being retired